# Difference between namespace install vs managed namespace install in Argo Workflows?

Tags: argo-workflows

I am trying to install argo workflows and looking at the documentation I can see 3 different types of installation https://argoproj.github.io/argo-workflows/installation/.

Can anybody give some clarity on the `namespace install` vs `managed namespace install`? If its a managed namespace, how can I tell the managed namespace? Should I edit the k8's manifest for deployment? What benefit it can provide compared to simple namespace install
?

Comment: There is a linked documentation page describing the managed namespace install option: https://argoproj.github.io/argo-workflows/managed-namespace/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A **namespace install** allows Workflows to run only in the namespace where Argo Workflows is installed.

A **managed namespace install** allows Workflows to run only in one namespace *besides* the one where Argo Workflows is installed.

Using a managed namespace install might make sense if you want some users/processes to be able to run Workflows without granting them any privileges in the namespace where Argo Workflows is installed.

For example, if I only run CI/CD-related Workflows that are maintained by the same team that manages the Argo Workflows installation, it's probably reasonable to use a namespace install. But if all the Workflows are run by a separate data science team, it probably makes sense to give them a `data-science-workflows` namespace and run a "managed namespace install" of Argo Workflows from another namespace.

To configure a managed namespace install, edit the `workflow-controller` and `argo-server` Deployments to pass the `--managed-namespace` argument.

You can currently only configure one managed namespace, but in the future it [may be possible to manage more than one](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/issues/6769).

Comment: Hi, is there any update on being able to manage multiple namespaces? The github issue you shared doesn't have any updates lately

Comment: @VikrantYadav still waiting on a contributor afaik. :-)

Comment: See also https://argoproj.github.io/argo-workflows/managed-namespace/